# Which interfaces satisfied from list of arbitrary interfaces?

Tags: interface, go

Is there a way I can determine which interfaces a concrete type implements from an
arbitrary list of interfaces? I'm aware of a type switch, but I'd like to know all satisfied
interfaces.

For example, given:

```
type Mover interface  { Move() }
type Talker interface { Talk() }
type Flyer interface  { Fly() }

type Person struct{}
func (a *Person) Move() {fmt.Println("Moving...") }
func (a *Person) Talk() {fmt.Println("Talking...") }
```

I can manually test each interface as follows:

```
func testInterfaces(entity interface{}) {

    _, ok := entity.(Mover)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("mover")
    }
    _, ok := entity.(Talker)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("talker")
    }
    _, ok := entity.(Flyer)
    if ok {
        fmt.Println("flyer")
    }
}
```

For a Person value, "mover", and "talker" will print. However, I'd rather have a function like this (non-working) one:

```
func testInterfaces2(entity interface{}, interfaceList type??) {
    for _, inter := range interfaceList {
        val, ok := entity.(inter)
        if ok {
            // do something with val
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve something like this pseudo function, maybe through the reflect package or some other means?

Comment: I'm not certain, so I won't post an answer, but I think interfaces are checked by comparison at runtime, there's no master list of satisfied interfaces. One potential reason for not having such a thing may allow the compiler to optimize-out unused interface data. I suspect what you're asking for doesn't exist, and would be unlikely to be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/qgJy_H2GysY) to get a slice of interface types.

Then, you can just check whether the `Type` of your value implements the interface as in [here](http://play.golang.org/p/-xd2UN9eA5):

```
interfaces := []reflect.Type{reflect.TypeOf((*Mover)(nil)).Elem(), 
    reflect.TypeOf((*Talker)(nil)).Elem(), 
    reflect.TypeOf((*Flyer)(nil)).Elem()}
p := &Person{}
t := reflect.TypeOf(p)
name := t.Elem().Name()
for _, interf := range interfaces {
    if t.Implements(interf) {
        fmt.Printf("%s is a %s\n", name, interf.Name())
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%s is NOT a %s\n", name, interf.Name())
    }
}
```

But I think the use of a Type switch is preferable if at all possible

Comment: Yup, after searching I figured out this trick to get an interface type. I'd also recommend only using this if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that go doesn't handle exceptionally well is generics. The Prefered way to do this is a type switch:

```
func testInterfaces2(entity interface{}) {
    switch entity.(type) {
    case Mover:
        fmt.Println("mover")
    case Talker:
        fmt.Println("talker")
    case Flyer:
        fmt.Println("flyer")
    default:
        fmt.Println("something else")
    }
}
```

But like val said, the way to get all of the interfaces that are implemented by a type is (a cleaned up version of val's code):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Mover interface  { Move() }
type Talker interface { Talk() }
type Flyer interface  { Fly() }

type Person struct{}
func (a *Person) Move() {fmt.Println("Moving...") }
func (a *Person) Talk() {fmt.Println("Talking...") }

func testInterfaces(entity interface{}, interfaces []reflect.Type) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(entity)
    name := t.Elem().Name()
    for _, interf := range interfaces {
            if t.Implements(interf) {
                fmt.Printf("%s is a %s\n", name, interf.Name())
            } else {
                fmt.Printf("%s is NOT a %s\n", name, interf.Name())
            }
    }
}

func main() {
    interfaces := []reflect.Type{
        reflect.TypeOf((*Mover)(nil)).Elem(), 
        reflect.TypeOf((*Talker)(nil)).Elem(), 
        reflect.TypeOf((*Flyer)(nil)).Elem(),
    }
    p := &Person{}
    testInterfaces(p, interfaces)
}
```

Here it is in go play: http://play.golang.org/p/6aqMx5CQvY

Comment: A type switch doesn't work because the switch exits after the Mover case is executed. "talker" is never printed despite the Talker interface being ok. I'd like to know ALL satisfied interfaces.